# paths from root to leaf of a binary tree in clojure

Tags: clojure, binary-tree, binary-search

I'm trying to implement a recursive function that can find all the paths from the root to the leaves in a binary tree in clojure, but I'm stuck. Here's an example of what the tree looks like:
[binary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzJw5.png)

I've been trying to find inspiration from the implementation in java https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-binary-tree-print-all-root-to-leaf-paths/ , but I still don't know how to write a similar function in clojure. This is the helper function I've written so far.

```
 (defn helper

[T P i]

(if (not (= nil T))
    (do (def P (conj P (T :value)))
        P
    )
)

(if (isbranch? T)
    (cond
       (and (not (= nil (T :left))) (= nil (T :right))) (helper (T :left) P (+ i 1))
       (and (not (= nil (T :right))) (= nil (T :left))) (helper (T :left) P (+ i 1))
       :else (do (helper (T :left) P (+ i 1)) (helper (T :left) P (+ i 1)))
    )
    (print P)
))
```

Could someone explain where I should start?

Comment: You're saying that you're stuck. But what have you actually tried? How do you represent that tree with Clojure data structures? In what form do you expect to get the result?

Comment: The tree is represented with a map and I tried to implement a helper funcion that's stimilar to the one on geeksforgeeks, but I don't really know how to turn java code into clojure and I want the result to be in a list.

Comment: Then please try your best, and add the code, and how it fails, to the question.

Comment: I tried to test this helper function but nothing works.

Comment: There is already a working answer, so I’ll try to explain why the Java method you tried to copy tripped you up: in Clojure, values are generally immutable. You need to learn to think in terms of functional programming: code takes in values and returns different values but never tries to change variables. You will never see `def` used in a function, only at the top level to define global values. Those will sometimes be atoms, which can be mutated with special techniques, but best to get familiar with functional coding first. Copying imperative examples that mutate variables won’t help that.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that you couldn't change values in a function, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It’s not that you _can’t_ change values in a function, tools like atoms allow you to change values in a thread-safe way, but you generally _don’t_ because that makes it easier to understand and debug groups of functions. So Clojure defaults to making values impossible to change, but easy to create and return new modified values from, in order to help with this approach. [Here’s](https://circleci.com/blog/functional-vs-object-oriented-programming/) a good introduction to these ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the tree is represented like this by reading the code in the question:

```
(def input {:value 10
            :left {:value 8 :left {:value 3} :right {:value 5}}
            :right {:value 2 :left {:value 2}}})
```

Apart from that, it is not clear to me how the code provided in the question is supposed to work.

Here is **recursive** solution that I suggest:

```
(defn- all-paths-recursive-sub [dst path {:keys [value left right]}]
  (let [children (remove nil? [left right])
        path (conj path value)]
    (if (empty? children)
      (conj dst path)
      (reduce (fn [dst subtree] (all-paths-recursive-sub dst path subtree))
              dst
              children))))

(defn all-paths-recursive [tree]
  (all-paths-recursive-sub [] [] tree))

(all-paths-recursive input)
;; => [[10 8 3] [10 8 5] [10 2 2]]
```

and here is an **iterative** solution:

```
(defn all-paths-iterative [tree]
  (loop [stack [[[] tree]]
         result []]
    (if (empty? stack)
      result
      (let [[[path {:keys [value left right]}] & stack] stack
            children (remove nil? [left right])
            path (conj path value)]
        (if (empty? children)
          (recur stack (conj result path))
          (recur (into stack (map (partial vector path)) children) result))))))

(all-paths-iterative input)
;; => [[10 2 2] [10 8 5] [10 8 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain how the recursive function works? I can't fully understand it

Comment: Yes: The recursive function takes as input a vector where it accumulates the result, the path to the current subtree and, as last argument, that subtree. It uses destructuring syntax in the argument list to get the value, left and right subtrees from that subtree. The left and right subtrees (if any) are put into a sequence called `children`. If that sequence is empty, the path is accumulated to the result. Otherwise, it uses `reduce` to recursively call itself on all the subtrees and accumulate the result.

Comment: Oh, ok. But is there anyway to add arrows (or other symbols that indicate if the path goes from left or right) between the values during the recursion? I tried to do that but it didn't work out.

Comment: I tried to replace the 3rd row with this "path (conj path value "->")" but then there's one arrow too much at the end and I also wanna try adding symbols (L R) between the values so I know how the path goes down

Comment: @Ares I suggest you write a function to print the path named `print-path`. Then you call it in a loop, something like `(doseq [path (all-paths-recursive input)] (print-path path))`. You could try `(defn print-path [p] (clojure.string/join " -> " (map str p)))`.

Answer (score 3):

I think Rulle's recursive solution is more complicated than necessary. `for` is the premier tool for turning sequences into other sequences, especially when they're nested, like a tree.

```
(defn paths-to-leaves [{:keys [left right value]}]
  (if (every? nil? [left right])
    [[value]]
    (for [child (filter some? [left right])
          path (paths-to-leaves child)]
      (cons value path))))
```

Most importantly, this solution is lazy, so you can use it on large trees without materializing all the paths at once. Of course, it still has to get to a leaf before it can produce the path to that leaf, but it doesn't have to look at all of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Specter** is a great tool for nested data. A solution based [using specter recursively](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter/wiki/Using-Specter-Recursively):

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :refer :all])

(def input {:value 10
            :left  {:value 8 :left {:value 3} :right {:value 5}}
            :right {:value 2 :left {:value 2}}})

(def leaf-paths
  (recursive-path [] RECUR
      (if-path #(some % [:left :right])
        [(collect-one :value) (submap [:left :right]) MAP-VALS RECUR]
        :value)))

(select leaf-paths input)
;; => [[10 8 3] [10 8 5] [10 2 2]]
```

Although I will confess that specter brings its own learning curve the above can be slightly modified into a navigator useful for both selection and modification:

```
(def leaf-values
  (recursive-path [] RECUR
      (if-path #(some % [:left :right])
        [(submap [:left :right]) MAP-VALS RECUR]
        :value)))

(select leaf-values input)
;; [3 5 2]

(transform leaf-values #(* 100 %) input)
;; {:value 10,
;;  :left {:value 8, :left {:value 300}, :right {:value 500}},
;;  :right {:value 2, :left {:value 200}}}
```